# Setting deadlines from datetime based on hour, weekday, weekends, and holidays

Tags: pandas, datetime

With the datetime data below I would like to set a deadline relative to the 'Date' based on the following criteria:

If a 'Date' is in Holidays or on a weekend, then the deadline should be the next business day at 17:00 hours.

If a 'Date' is on Monday-Friday, not a holiday, AND the hour of the 'Date' is between 0-8, then the deadline should be the same business day at 17:00 hours

If a 'Date' is on Monday-Friday, not a holiday, AND the hour of the 'Date' is between 9-17, then the deadline should be the next non-holiday, business day at the same time.

If a 'Date' is on Monday-Friday, not a holiday, AND the hour of the 'Date' is between 18-23, then the deadline should be the next non-holiday, business day at 17:00 hours

Below is the data:

```
import datetime

Holidays = [date(2018,1,1),date(2018,1,15),date(2018,2,19),date(2018,3,9)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-01-01 18:47','2018-01-08 06:11','2018-01-12 10:05','2018-02-10 09:22','2018-02-20 14:14','2018-03-08 16:17','2018-03-25 17:35'],
                   'Weekday': [0,0,4,5,1,3,6],
                   'Hour': [18,6,10,9,14,16,17]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

The result should be as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018-01-01 18:47','2018-01-08 06:11','2018-01-12 10:05','2018-02-10 09:22','2018-02-21 14:14','2018-03-08 16:17','2018-03-25 17:35'],
               'Deadline': ['2018-01-02 17:00','2018-01-08 17:00','2018-01-16 10:05','2018-02-12 17:00','2018-02-22 14:14','2018-03-12 16:17','2018-03-26 17:00']})
```

Comment: How confident are you in your desired output?  For your third column, the time is between 9-17, yet your desired result is *not* at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Writing down your condition one by one , then we using `np.select`

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *

df.loc[df.Date.isin(Holidays),'WeekDay']=5#here I assign the holiday week to 5 in case we can consider the weekends and holiday in the same .
```

---

```
#make the conditions
con0=df.Weekday.isin([5,6]).values
con1=(df.Weekday.between(0,4)&df.Date.dt.hour.between(0,8)).values
con2=(df.Weekday.between(0,4)&df.Date.dt.hour.between(9,17)).values
con3=(df.Weekday.between(0,4)&df.Date.dt.hour.between(18,23)).values
```

---

```
# value to select 
s=(df['Date'] + BDay())
s=pd.Series(np.where(s.dt.date.isin(Holidays),s+BDay(),s))# create your own bdays
r0=s.apply(lambda x : x.replace(hour=17,minute =0,second =0)).values
r1=df['Date'].apply(lambda x : x.replace(hour=17,minute =0,second =0)).values
r2=(s).values
r3=r0
```

---

```
# using np.select get the output 
np.select([con0,con1,con2,con3],[r0,r1,r2,r3],default=np.datetime64('2005-02-25'))
Out[635]: 
array(['2018-01-02T17:00:00.000000000', '2018-01-08T17:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-01-16T10:05:00.000000000', '2018-02-12T17:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-02-21T14:14:00.000000000', '2018-03-12T16:17:00.000000000',
       '2018-03-26T17:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: I think you'd need to define a custom set of holidays for `BDay()` to use, since one of the outputs is `2018-01-15` which is in the list of Holidays.

Comment: @user3483203 yes you are right , I try to define it :-)

Comment: @Wen Thanks for the help on solving this problem of mine. If for con1 I wanted the deadline to be the next business day at 17:00 hours, how could I go about altering the code to get that.